# Derivative of differentiable increasing function

Tags: real-analysis

For an everywhere differentiable increasing function $u:E=[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $, we know that $$Var(E)=Var(E_{\infty})+ \int_E |u’|= \int_E |u’|=u(b)-u(a) $$
It implies that $u’ \in L^1([a,b])$, but if we can get that $u’$ is bounded?

Comment: NO. $u'$ can be unbounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists a strictly increasing differentiable $u:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ such that $u'$ is unbounded on $[0,1].$

(1). If  $x<x_1$ and $y<y_1$ and  $n\in \Bbb N$ there is a strictly increasing differentiable  $f:[x,x_1]\to [y,y_1]$ with $f(x)=y$ and $f(x_1)=y_1$ and $f'(x)=f'(x_1)=0,$ such that $\sup \{f'(z):z\in [x,x_1]\}\geq n.$

(2).  For $n\in \Bbb N$ let $a_n=1-2^{1-n}$ and let $u(a_n)=1-4^{1-n}.$ Let  $u$ be strictly increasing and differentiable on $[a_n,a_{n+1}]$ with $u'(a_n)=u'(a_{n+1})=0,$ and such that $\sup\{u'(x):x\in [a_n,a_{n+1}]\}\geq n.$

Let $u(1)=1.$ We need to show that $u'(1)$ exists.   If $0\leq x<1$ then $a_n\leq x<a_{n+1}$ for some $n,$ so $$0<\frac {u(1)-u(x)}{1-x}=\frac {1-u(x)}{1-x}< \frac {1-u(a_n)}{1-a_{n+1}}=2^{2-n}.$$  Since $n\to \infty$ as $x\to 1,$ we have $u'(1)=0.$

So $u:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ is strictly increasing and differentiable  but $\sup \{u'(x):x\in [0,1]\}=\infty.$

Comment: An example of $f$ in part (1): Let $M=(x+x_1)/2$ and $V=(y+y_1)/2. $ For $z\in [x,M]$  let $f(z)=y+K_m(z-x)^m$ where $2\leq m\in \Bbb N$ and $K_m=M^{-m}V$ , so that $f(M)=V.$ ... For the graph of $f$ for $z\in [M, x_1]$, rotate  the graph of $f$ on $[x,M]$  through $180$ degrees about the point $(M,V).$.. We have $f'(M)= mV/M.$ .... So let $m$ be large enough that $mV/M\geq n.$

Comment: ERRATA. In  my previous comment to this Q it should say $K_m=(V-y)(M-x)^{-m}.$ And it should say  $f'(M)=m(V-y)/(M-x)$.... So choose $m\geq 2$ and large enough that $m(V-y)/(M-x)\geq n.$

Comment: The idea was that u(x) approaches u(1)=1 rapidly enough that u'(1)=0, but that u'(x) can  take some large values on increasingly tiny intervals, so that u  itself can't grow much on these intervals